# Check if a mouse is over a div

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check to see if there is a mouse over a div on my website? I need the constant verification. If the mouse is over the div content appears and when isn't, the content disappears.

The content that appears needs to also include/allow links.

Comment: Where is your markup, javascript code and your attempts?

Comment: Onmouseover? Onmousemove? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SHOW DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oHUXIxi/1/edit)

jQuery:

```
$(document).on({

    mouseenter: function () {

        alert("Hello");

    },
    mouseleave: function () {

        // alert("Bye");
    }
}, "#div");
```

Comment: tks, you solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

just check `$(select).is(':hover')`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without JavaScript if you would like. Div's respond to the `:hover`pseudo-class.

You could do something like:

```
#myCoolDiv {
    /*Styles go here*/
    display: none;
}
#myCoolDiv:hover {
    display: block /*Or whatever display type you want*/
}
```

Of course, that will make the div disappear entirely. You could just assign the hover to certain text inside the div if you want some of it to be visible and some of it to be invisible until hover.

More details on hover [over on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover).

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that once the element is hiden the hover also stops?

Comment: That's why I put that addendum at the bottom. He can use class or element selectors from there to hide certain items. Without sample code posted, I didn't have a lot to go off, so I attempted post a somewhat general solution.

Answer (score 1):

i fund this code here, but this only give me the mouse position, in the window, not relative to a div

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
        var IE = document.all ? true : false;
        if (!IE) {
            document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
        }

        document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

        var tempX = 0;
        var tempY = 0;

        function getMouseXY(e) {
            if (IE) {// grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
                tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
                tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
            } else {// grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
                tempX = e.pageX;
                tempY = e.pageY;
            }
            if (tempX < 0) {
                tempX = 0;
            }
            if (tempY < 0) {
                tempY = 0;
            }
            document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;
            document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY;
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the css `:hover` option [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).  You can have it as a style that you can apply to divs, links, whatever you need.  That is triggers when the mouse is over the element.

Answer (score 0):

With css style (Easiest way)
So for example when we mouse over, background will change to blue color

In your page:

```
<div id="my_div">This text is in my div!</div>
```

In your css file:

```
#my_div {
background-color: white;
}

#my_div:hover {
background-color: blue;
}
```

Of course you can check it with javascript too.